# Repeating of code

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to shorten this it feels like i am repeating code, and looks very untidy?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();


$('#b1').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text1').fadeIn(800);
});

$('#b2').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text2').fadeIn(800);
});

$('#b3').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text3').fadeIn(800);
});

$('#b4').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text4').fadeIn(800);
});

$('#b5').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text5').fadeIn(800);
});

$('#b6').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text6').fadeIn(800);
});


$('#b7').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text7').fadeIn(800);
});

});
```

Comment: Can you share the corresponding markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#b1,#b2,#b3,#b4,#b5,#b6').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text'+this.id.substr(-1)).fadeIn(800);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

add `class` to b elements for example:

```
<div id="b1" class="b"></div>
<div id="b2" class="b"></div>
<div id="b3" class="b"></div>
```

and use `class` to click event

```
$('.b').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text'+this.id.substr(-1)).fadeIn(800);
});
```

OR

```
<div id="b1" class="b" data-text="#text1"></div>
<div id="b2" class="b" data-text="#text2"></div>
<div id="b3" class="b" data-text="#text3"></div>


$('.b').click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $((this).data("text")).fadeIn(800);
});
```

AS @joeframbach suggestion

Comment: Or even, <div id="b1" class="b" data-ref="#text1"></div>, and $($(this).data('ref')).fadeIn(800);

Answer (score 1):

Create a new function that accepts a number as a parameter, then add the strings together:

```
$('#b' + id).click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text' + id).fadeIn(800);
});
```

In this case `id` is the parameter.

Afterwards you can create a `for` loop to run that function over and over again. In the condition where you need to add something, this pretty much makes your life easy.

Answer (score 1):

you can assign a class and after make something like this (if you put into your element class "bclass")

```
$('.bclass').click(function(){
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text'+this.id.substr(-1)).fadeIn(800);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you can refactor this is by putting al the b# elements in a div tag and then select that div tag with it's id/class and use `.children()` to get all the b# elements.

Example:

```
$('#mydiv').children().click(function() {
    $('.allText').hide();
    $('#text2').fadeIn(800);
});
```